# Simple jQuery slider repeating

Tags: jquery, html, slider, fade, repeat

I'm trying to make a simple jquery slider that infinitely repeats. I've put the class "hidden" on the item that is hidden, and the class "featured" on the item that is not hidden. The plan is then to make it switch between them with a fade animation.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to add the class "hidden" to the featured item, without it being changed back to "featured" right after.

How do I do this? This is my current jQuery code:

```
        var fadeTime = 2500;
        var slideInterval = 5000;

        $("article.hidden").hide();


        function aSlider(){     
            $("article.featured").removeClass("featured").addClass("hidden")
            $("article.hidden").removeClass("hidden").addClass("featured").fadeIn(fadeTime);
        };

        setInterval(aSlider, 5000);
```

Thanks,

Marius

Answer (score 0):

The error is inside your code:

when you run the first line:

```
$("article.featured").removeClass("featured").addClass("hidden")
```

then you run the second **you act on the one that you have just changed!**

```
$("article.hidden").removeClass("hidden").addClass("featured").fadeIn(fadeTime);
```

Here your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Madthew/39w8Z/3/